# $SU(2)$ bundles over a flat Euclidean $\mathbb{R}^d$ or Minkowski $\mathbb{R}^{d,1}$ space?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, geometric-topology, gauge-theory

I know that we can have a $U(1)$ bundle over the base manifold like $S^2$. For example, we can choose the fibre $U(1)=S^1$ over $S^2$ as the $S^3$ Hopf fibration.

I know that we can have a $SU(2)$ bundle over the base manifold like $S^4$. For example, we can choose the fibre $SU(2)=S^3$ over $S^4$ as the $S^7$ Hopf fibration. Correct me if I was wrong!

Now, can we have any nontrivial $SU(2)$ bundles over a flat Euclidean $\mathbb{R}^d$ or Minkowski $\mathbb{R}^{d,1}$ space??

If so, could you give some examples?

If not, could you give me a proof? (or at least sketch your arguments to convince me?)

Comment: So it does not depend on which principal G bundle that I look at?

Comment: Yes; all fiber bundles over contractible spaces are trivial.

Comment: contractible space: You meant all homotopy groups are zeros? $\pi_n(M)=0$ for all $n$?

Comment: How about Minkowski space $\mathbb{R}^{d,1}$? Can there be nontrivial bundles over a flat space $\mathbb{R}^{d,1}$ with metric $(+++++...+-)?

Comment: I adjust my question.

Comment: By contractible I mean homotopy equivalent to a point. Triviality is a topological property; you don't need to put a metric on any of the spaces involved, and it does not depend on the choice of metric if you do.